# Dismissing popover, then popToRootViewController, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone

I am getting a crash when I `popToRootViewController`, this is the way I have it set up.

I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popover;
```

in dealloc:

```
[popover release];
```

when a button is pressed

```
if (self.popover == nil) {
    DetailViewController *detailView = [[[DetailViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(GoToTest:) name:TestDetailPressed object:detailView];
    self.popover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailView] autorelease];
    self.popover.delegate = self;
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.scrollView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

My `DetailViewController` is essentially just a `UITableView`.  When a row is selected, I post a notification back to this current class for GoToTest:

```
- (void)GoToTest:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([self.popover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popover dismisspopoverAnimated:YES];
        [self handleDismissedPopover:self.popover];
    }
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

- (void)handleDismissedPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    self.popover = nil;
    self.popover.delegate = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:TestDetailPressed object:nil];
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    [self handleDismissedPopover:popoverController;
}
```

When I run it in Instruments, I get the zombie message for

```
 -[UIPopoverController _popoverDismissAnimationCompleted]
```

and the `UIViewController` has a refCt of -1 at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to change `self.popover = nill` to `popover = nil` because the first (`self.popover = nil`) will call the property setter, which releases the old value and sets the member to nil.  Also, put the delegate nil before the property nil.

To fix, change this:

```
- (void)handleDismissedPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    self.popover = nil;
    self.popover.delegate = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:TestDetailPressed object:nil];
}
```

To:

```
- (void)handleDismissedPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    popover.delegate = nil;
    popover = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:TestDetailPressed object:nil];
}
```

---

And if that doesn't work, set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: I would have imagined the popover.delegate = nil; after the popover = nil; is pointless.

Comment: @chown What does malloc:recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder mean?

Comment: @JW it just means that all memory allocation is being logged to a file.

Comment: @jbat100 fixing the delegate before setting the popover to nil fixed my problem.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, are you explicitly calling:

```
[popever release];
```

in dealloc? Since you do this:

```
self.popover = nil;
```

that will release the object and you don't need to worry about it in your dealloc. But yeah, like @chown says, use Instruments Zombie tool and it'll tell you right away what's up.